# Why the nested wwwroot is hidden to the kudu console?

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure.

I was able to use the Microsoft bot Composer to publish my first chatbot to the azure window web service. I also log into the azure portal to use the edge browser to open up KuDu Console.
I also open up the corresponding shell. I can use the shell (such as the cmd or powershell) to trace the nested wwwroot. But, the nested wwwroot is hidden from the kudu console?  Why the azure window web service wants to keep the nested wwwroot hidden from the KuDu console?  In anther word, the kudu console only displays the top-level wwwroot while keeping the sub-level wwwroot hidden from being discovered.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, It's due to the sandbox restrictions.
All Azure Web Apps run in a secure environment called a sandbox. Each app runs inside its own sandbox, isolating its execution from other instances on the same machine as well as providing an additional degree of security and privacy which would otherwise not be available.

The sandbox generally aims to restrict access to shared components of Windows.
Applications are highly restricted in terms of their access of the file system.

I suggest you to check these docs for more information on this:

[Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#file-system-restrictionsconsiderations)

[Accessing the kudu service](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service)

[Operating system functionality on Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/operating-system-functionality)